# Convert/View PowerPoint file into/in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, powerpoint

I have a game of jeopardy that I made in PowerPoint and I was wondering if I could have a Silverlight application read the ppt file. Or is there a way to convert a .ppt file to a Silverlight readable format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few options available, none of them "great".

1. **pptx2silverlight** on [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/pptx2silverlight)

   - Pros: Freely available code
   - Cons: Simplistic player, no animation/audio/video, conversion of slides to PNGs
2. **Convexion** by [ElectricRain](http://www.erain.com/products/convexion/)

   - Pros: Converts most animations/transitions
   - Cons: No audio/video support, converts shapes to PNGs (not XAML), creates "loose XAML" instead of compiled code
3. **Powerlight** by [Conaito](http://www.conaito.com/powerlight-powerpoint-xps-silverlight-converter.asp)

   - Pros: Cheapest commercial solution, more customizable player
   - Cons: no animation/audio/video, conversion of slides to PNGs

Comment: Convexion *claims* to support embedded audio/video, but I haven't actually seen it work yet.  Not sure if they expect specific formats, etc.  (We're using the Pro version...)

Comment: @GalacticCowboy: Interesting. I hadn't even seen the claim :)  But I haven't checked in a while. I think the main issue is everything that I have with it (as well as the others) is that everything is is turned into PNGs. You have enough PNGs and it's no longer a small file. Those Convexion SL examples are huge. At least PPT->Flash converters make smaller files for the web.

Answer (score 1):

If you can save the .ppt file as a .pptx file then it will be in a zipped XML format that you could read with Silverlight. But you don't want to read it (it's a very complex format).

You just want to convert it with something like this: http://www.codeplex.com/pptx2silverlight

Answer (score 1):

There's a commercial app called [Convexion](http://www.erain.com/products/convexion/) from ElectricRain that converts to wpf and silverlight. It'll run ya $149 though, so not quite as good as a free tool such as pptx2silverlight, as Gabe mentioned.

However: it preserves things such as animations, which may or may not be important to you.